# $g(x)\le f_0(x_0)$ for all $g \in B$ and $x \in A$.

Tags: analysis

I want to prove the statement :

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^{n}$ be compact and let $B \subset C(A,\Bbb R^{n})$ be compact.
>
> Show that there are an $f_0 \in B$ and an  $x_0 \in A$ such that $g(x)\le f_0(x_0)$ for all $g \in B$ and $x \in A$.

I think key is compactness of A and B and norm function is continuous.

But I can't solve if $||f_0(x_0)||$ is in fact the absolute minimum of $f_0$ so that $f_0(x_0)\lt0$.

Comment: It suffices to show that $A\times C(A,\mathbb R^n)\to\mathbb R^n,(x,f)\mapsto f(x)$ is continuous. Note that $A$ is locally compact.

Comment: Thanks~ But why did you note that A is locally compact?
Can I just use A x B is compact?